# Parsing an array of objects, do some math with their index

Tags: jq

I have a large json which is actually a concatenated array of objects from several configuration files. I would like to use them to bring up a menue in a bash script. To make the menue easier to read, the json array contains special objects that would trigger a line break. In the end, the user picks the index of the array.

A simplified json looks like this:

```json
[
        {
                "index" : 0,
                "value" : "one a"
        },
        {
                "index" : 3,
                "value" : "two a"
        },
        {
                "value" : ""
        },
        {
                "index" : 2,
                "value" : "three a"
        },
        {
                "value" : ""
        },
        {
                "index" : 1,
                "value" : "one b"
        },
        {
                "index" : 3,
                "value" : "two b"
        },
        {
                "index" : 2,
                "value" : "three b"
        }
]
```

All values with **a** come from the first file, all **b**s from the second file. The entries with an empty value are line breaks.

What I got so far, after hours of researching, is this:

```bash
jq --raw-output 'to_entries[] | "\(.key + 1). \(.value.value) (\(.value.index))"' test.json
```

Which produces this out of the above data:

```
1. one a (0)
2. two a (3)
3.  (null)
4. three a (2)
5.  (null)
6. one b (1)
7. two b (3)
8. three b (2)
```

Now the user would type **8** to work with the **three b**.

What I need, however, is this:

```
1. one a (0)
2. two a (3)

3. three a (2)

4. one b (1)
5. two b (3)
6. three b (2)
```

So the user would need to type **6** to do the same.

Any idea welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `foreach` to count would be one way:

```bash
foreach .[] as {$index, $value} (0;
  if $value != "" then . + 1 else . end;
  if $value != "" then "\(.). \($value) (\($index))" else "" end
)
```

```
1. one a (0)
2. two a (3)

3. three a (2)

4. one b (1)
5. two b (3)
6. three b (2)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/urs3FXTpBkU)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think I'm starting to develop a love/hate relationship to jq (similar to awk). Would you mind pointing out how to filter correctly so **4** would return "one b (1)"?

Comment: Hah, got it! 

jq 'map(select(.value != "")) | .[6]' test.json

Comment: Left padding the number with zeroes up to 2 chars doesn't seem easy to me.

Comment: @AndréB You could write your own padding function, e.g. as `def pad($n): (log10 | $n - floor - 1) * "0" + "\(.)";` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ood-mx1jinp)

Comment: thanks. I went this way: `"\(. | "000" + tostring | .[-2:]).` - dirty, but works, as I'm not expecting numbers > 20

Comment: @AndréB Drop `. |` as it generally serves no purpose. If you only take the last two digits, prepending just `"0"` will suffice (the counter starts with having one digit already). And if your goal with the "dirty" solution is shorter code, you can use string interpolation again instead of `tostring`: `"\("0\(.)"[-2:]). …"`

Comment: thanks! I start to like jq ;-)